# Set environment variable in tmux status

Tags: shell, tmux

I'm trying to show two different time zones within my tmux status. I have a command that uses the unix `date` utility which works when executed within my shell.

```
echo $(TZ=':US/Pacific' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S' && TZ=':Europe/London' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S')
```

Produces: `PDT 04:05:59 BST 12:05:59`

However, it seems like the environment variable `TZ` is clobbered when I execute this command within tmux.

```
set -g status-right "#(echo $(TZ=':US/Pacific' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S' && TZ=':Europe/London' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S'))"
```

Displays: `PDT 04:09:01 PDT 04:09:01` in my tmux status bar.

I can solve this by writing a small shell script that executes one localized date command at a time but I don't want to depend on an extra file. I've tried using `eval` but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

The following does also not work.

```
set -g status-right "#(echo $(TZ=':US/Pacific' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S')) #(echo $(TZ=':Europe/London' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S'))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to escape the % with another % as as tmux passes the times through strftime

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, the `tmux` status-bar can't display multiline output in the status bar. It only displays the first line of the output. So I have to print date without newline and concatenate the output.

```
set -g status-right "#(echo -n $(TZ=':US/Pacific' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S ') && echo -n ' ' && echo -n $(TZ=':Europe/London' date '+%Z %H:%M:%S'))"
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is regarding multiline output in the status bar. I've updated the question to show another tmux status bar config that also does not work and consists of multiple commands.

Comment: But it works in my environment. Sorry, I don't know the problem, maybe I need to take some time to figure out. Maybe I couldn't figure it out. @mikeecb